# JavaScript: Get $(this) in even handler when using referenced function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my understanding of JavaScript. I want to convert the following working code:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this)); // w.fn.init [div... (lots of stuff here)
);
```

convert to:

```
button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick(e) );

function handleButtonClick (e) {
  console.log(e) // MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1418, screenY: 295, clientX: 683, clientY: 151, …}
}
```

How can I get the `$(this)` from the original code in the converted version using the referenced function? I've tried using `bind` but it didn't work, most likely because I did it wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function and passing its return value(which is `undefined` in above case) to the eventlistener. You just have to pass the variable without calling it

You can get the button element using `e.target` or `this`

```
button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick );

function handleButtonClick (e) {
  console.log(e.target) // MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1418, screenY: 295, clientX: 683, clientY: 151, …}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had to do console.log($(e.target)) to fully replicate the functionality of the original code. The `(e)` after `handleButtonClick` just sneaked in when creating this minimal example.